# Add link in table in Web App (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am creating a web application using Google Apps Script. The objective is to have a course listing in a table. This table has three columns (one for the tool concerned, one for the type of file and one for the name of the file).
This data is taken from a Sheets file. The data is correctly displayed in the web app.

However, I would like the last column to show the name of the file and, for it, to be a clickable link back to the course (preferably on a new page).

I don't know how to do this, I tried with setAttribute but it gives me an error.

Here is a part of the html code of the page:

```
    <div class="form-row divBloc">
       <div class="form-group col-md-7">
       <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm text-center align-middle table-striped">
         <thead id="thead">
           <tr class="text-center">
             <th scope="col" class="align-middle" id="libOutil">Outil</th>
             <th scope="col" class="align-middle" id="libTypeSupport">Type de support</th>
             <th scope="col" class="align-middle" id="libNomFichier">Nom du fichier</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>

         <!-- AFFICHAGE DES RÉSULTATS LORS D'UNE RECHERCHE -->
         <tbody id="searchResults">
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
     </div>

     <!-- AFFICHAGE DES RÉSULTATS -->
     <template id="rowTemplate">
       <tr class="result-box" id="tableResults">
         <td class="align-middle classOutil" id="resultOutil"></td>
         <td class="align-middle classTypeSupport" id="resultTypeSupport"></td>
         <td class="align-middle classNomFichier" id="resultNomFichier"></td>
       </tr>
     </template>
```

Here is a part of the apps script code:

```
function getDataForSearch(outil1,outil2,outil3,outil4,outil5,outil6,outil7,outil8,outil9){
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName('BDD Documentation');
   var tDonnees = [];
   var data = feuille.getRange("A2:E").getValues().filter(d=>d[0]!="");
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
     if(data[i][0]){
       if (data[i][1] == outil1 || data[i][1] == outil2 || data[i][1] == outil3 || 
           data[i][1] == outil4 || data[i][1] == outil5 || data[i][1] == outil6 || 
           data[i][1] == outil7 || data[i][1] == outil8 || data[i][1] == outil9){
         tDonnees.push([data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3]]);
       }
     }
   }
   return tDonnees;  
 }
```

And here is a part of the JavaScript code:

```
  // Fonction permettant de récupérer les documents 
   function setDataForSearch(){
     loadingStart();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
       data = dataReturned.slice();
       search();
       loadingEnd();
     }).getDataForSearch("Sheets","Docs","Gmail","Drive","Forms","Slides","Contacts","Agenda","Slides");
   }

   // Fonction permettant d'afficher les résultats en fonction du contenu ou non de la barre de recherche
   function search(){
     var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
     var searchWords = searchInput.split(/\s+/);
     var searchColumns = [0,1,2,3];
     var resultsArray = searchInput === "" ? data : data.filter(function(r){
       return searchWords.every(function(word){
         return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
           return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1;
         });
       });
     });
     if(resultsArray.length>1){
       var recordCount = searchInput === "" ? "" : "Nombre de documents : " + resultsArray.length;
     } else {
       var recordCount = searchInput === "" ? "" : "Nombre de document : " + resultsArray.length;
     }
     document.getElementById("searchCounter").textContent = recordCount;
     var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
     var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
     var template = templateBox.content;
     searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";
     resultsArray.forEach(function(r){
       var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
       var outil = tr.querySelector(".classOutil");
       var typeSupport = tr.querySelector(".classTypeSupport");
       var nomFichier = tr.querySelector(".classNomFichier");
       outil.textContent = r[0];
       typeSupport.textContent = r[1];
       nomFichier.textContent = r[2];
       
       // nomFichier.textContent = document.createElement("a");
       // nomFichier.setAttribute = ("href", r[3]);
       // var linkText = document.createTextNode(r[2]);
       // nomFichier.appendChild(linkText);

       searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
     });
   }
```

I have commented on the part of the search() function that does not work and is blocking me.

Here is [the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JlyDAkTo_4QLvuNKI9SM6cd6oryqdCk209mI0VXFbnc/edit?usp=sharing) to the Sheets file if you want to look for yourself.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to add the file's URL in your source spreadsheet.

Then, you could modify your .gs like this :

```
     //data[i][4] : url of the file
     tDonnees.push([ data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], data[i][4] ]);
```

(It's possible to improve even better this part, if you have all files in the same directory, search by name, and get url)

```
     <!-- AFFICHAGE DES RÉSULTATS -->
     <template id="rowTemplate">
       <tr class="result-box" id="tableResults">
         <td class="align-middle classOutil" id="resultOutil"></td>
         <td class="align-middle classTypeSupport" id="resultTypeSupport"></td>
         <td class="align-middle classNomFichier" id="resultNomFichier"></td>
         <!-- new element -->
         <td class="align-middle classUrl"><a id="resultUrlFile" href="" target="_blank">LINK</a></td>
       </tr>
     </template>
```

And then change the `href` value with Javascript :

```
     resultsArray.forEach(function(r){
       var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
       var outil = tr.querySelector(".classOutil");
       var typeSupport = tr.querySelector(".classTypeSupport");
       var nomFichier = tr.querySelector(".classNomFichier");
       outil.textContent = r[0];
       typeSupport.textContent = r[1];
       nomFichier.textContent = r[2];

       //new lines : 
       var UrlFile= tr.querySelector(".classUrl > a");
       UrlFile.href = r[3];

       searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
     });
```